# How to design tables to allow for multi-field query on one row

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I am very new to database design and am using MS Access to try achieve my task. I am trying to create a database design that will allow for the name and description of two items to be queried 
on a single row of information. Here is the problem: certain items are converted to other particular items - 
any item can have multiple conversions performed on it, and all conversions will have two (many) items involved.
In this sense, we have a many-to-many relationship which necessitates the use of an intermediate table. My 
tables must be structured in a way that allows for me to, in one row, query the Item ID's and names
of which items were involved in conversions.

My current table layout is as follows:

```
Items 
+--------+----------+------------------+--+
| ItemID*| ItemName | ItemDescription  |  |
+--------+----------+------------------+--+
|      1 | DESK     | WOOD, 4 LEG      |  |
|      2 | SHELF    | WOOD, SOLID BASE |  |
|      3 | TABLE    | WOOD, 4 LEG      |  |
+--------+----------+------------------+--+


ItemConversions
+------------------+--------------+
| ConversionID(CK) | Item1_ID(CK) |
+------------------+--------------+
|                1 |            2 |
|                2 |            2 |
|                3 |            1 |
+------------------+--------------+

Conversions
+---------------+----------+----------+
| ConversionID* | Item1_ID | Item2_ID |
+---------------+----------+----------+
|             1 |        2 |        1 |
|             2 |        2 |        3 |
|             3 |        1 |        3 |
+---------------+----------+----------+
```

What I want is for it to be *possible* to achieve the kind of query I described above, though I don't think 
my current layout is going to work for this, since the tables are only being joined on Item1_ID. Any advice
would be appreciated, hopefully my tables are not too specific and this is easily understandable.

A sample query output might look like this:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| ConversionID | Item1_ID | ItemName | Item2_ID | ItemName |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|            1 |        2 | SHELF    |        1 | DESK     |
+--------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: So maybe you need to join ItemConversions with Conversions and also join Items to Item1_ID and Item2_ID? This means pulling Items into the query twice, the second will have an alias name like Items_1. Access query designer will assign that alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working how I wanted to with the help of June7's suggestion - I didn't know you could add in tables 
multiple times in the query design page (very useful!). As for the tables, I edited the layout so that I have only 
Items and Conversions (I deleted ItemConversions). Using the AS sql command I was able to write a query that pulls
the data I want from the tables. The table and query layout can be seen below:

```
Items 
+--------+----------+------------------+--+
| ItemID*| ItemName | ItemDescription  |  |
+--------+----------+------------------+--+
|      1 | DESK     | WOOD, 4 LEG      |  |
|      2 | SHELF    | WOOD, SOLID BASE |  |
|      3 | TABLE    | WOOD, 4 LEG      |  |
+--------+----------+------------------+--+

Conversions
+---------------+----------+----------+
| ConversionID* | Item1_ID | Item2_ID |
+---------------+----------+----------+
|             1 |        2 |        1 |
|             2 |        2 |        3 |
|             3 |        3 |        1 |
+---------------+----------+----------+


Query:

SELECT
   Conversions.ConversionID,
   Conversions.Item1_ID,
   Conversions.Item2_ID,
   Items.ItemName,
   Items_1.ItemName,
FROM
   (
      Conversions 
      INNER JOIN
         Items 
         ON Conversions.Item1_ID = Items.ItemID
   )
   INNER JOIN
      Items AS Items_1 
      ON Conversions.Item2_ID = Items_1.ItemID;
```